# how to make handsontable grid RTL?

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid, handsontable

I have used handsontable script to create a dynamic grid, but my grid must a RTL.
When I make it RTL it shows something like this.

[image: handsontable]

the definition is like this :

```
    $('#invoice_items-grid').handsontable({
        width: '80%',
        startRows: 3,
        startCols: 7,
        rowHeaders: true,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        colHeaders: true,
        undo: true,
        outsideClickDeselects : true ,
        enterBeginsEditing : true ,
        autoWrapRow : true ,
        autoWrapCol : true ,
        fillHandle: true //possible values: true, false, "horizontal", "vertical"
    });
```

thanks for your help.

Regards
Mohammad

Comment: I'm using handsontable grid on my Arabic RTL systems, it's not working when the CSS direction is RTL,  you will need to create your own counter column and build the columns from the end to the start